# Should we have a tag for Pi-Gen related questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

The search for `pi-gen` and `pigen` currently shows 56 questions related to/mentioning that topic. Is this enough to warrant a "pi-gen" tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. A lot of tags get created the first time something is asked about, there's no need to wait for a minimum threshold, as long as you are sure there's nothing synonymous.

You need 300 rep to create a tag, so I've done that:

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi-gen

Actually adding them is a normal edit, which you would need approved if you want to do this, but that should not be a problem.

Comment: The threshold is 300 reputation, so I can't propose the new tag. But as far as I have checked, there doesn't seem to be a synonymous tag, so there should not be a reason not to.

Comment: Right, sorry.  I've created it but not written a blurb, lemme know if you can't do that: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi-gen

Comment: Done, thank you! Now it just has to get past review ... ;)